# Issue with the customization of loginfrom.cmp and loginfromcontroller

Tags: community, login

I have customized the login page of the community, where I have changed the `loginform.cmp` and `loginformHelper.js` and `loginformcontroller`. But now in the login form the user name and password field are not appearing. When kept a `console.log` in the `helper.js` to check `isusernamepasswordenabledmethod` is null.

When I load the login page of community, I get this page:

[image: login page]

When I give a hardcoded `true` in the `rtnvalue` of the `loginformhelper.js isusernameandpasswordEnabled()` method, I see the screen like this:

[image: login page]

Why is this behavior happening?

Comment: Did we get the answer of above issue? Is it possible to modify the code of standard LoginForm.cmp component which is provided by salesforce. I am able to modify the the component but the changes are not reflecting when I try to login to communities after modifying the LoginForm.cmp component.